# Dislay id and name in a route path - Angular

Tags: angular, typescript

I would like to change a URL path in a website path from `http://localhost:4200/viewbrand/1` to `http://localhost:4200/viewbrand/1/soap` ie. to include a name after the ID.

The existing code in routing module.ts file:

```
{ path: 'viewbrand/:id', component: LocalbrandsComponent },
```

Existing code in HTML file:

```
 <a class="tile-link" href="/viewbrand/{{brand.id}}"></a>
```

I would think the change would be as follows to the module.ts file and the HTML file.

```
{ path: 'viewbrand/:id'/:brand.name, component: LocalbrandsComponent }

<a class="tile-link" href="/viewbrand/{{brand.id}}/{{brand.name}}"></a>
```

Does this follow the correct logic? It does not work.

Comment: No you can’t have a runtime variable in the router like that. However, why would just :brand not suffice? You can then read the brand param in your component. Plus, hou don’t need that many routes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I intially thought you want to redirect from the old url to the new one, but I think you're just trying to edit the url, in which case you haven't put the full path inside quotations.

```js
{ path: 'viewbrand/:id/:name', component: LocalbrandsComponent }
```

```html
<a class="tile-link" href="/viewbrand/{{brand.id}}/{{brand.name}}"></a>
```

If that's the case, I'm a bit concerned your IDE didn't let you know about that. Anyways, the redirect solution is below as well.

---

This is doable, but you need an intermediary component to extract the name and then redirect to the new route.

```js
{ path: 'viewbrand/:id', component: RedirectComponent },
{ path: 'viewbrand/:id/:name', component: LocalbrandsComponent },
```

```js
export class RedirectComponent {
  constructor(private router: Router, private route: ActivatedRoute) {}

  getName(id: string) {
    return 'name-for-' + id;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    const id = this.route.snapshot.params['id'];
    const name = this.getName(id);
    this.router.navigate(['viewbrand', id, name]);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use values that will be dynamically rendered in route.